# How small can a spark-gap transmitter be made?

Tags: rf, transmitter, spark

How small can a spark-gap transmitter be made?  Wikipedia's got plenty of pictures ranging from "desk-sized" to "room-sized", but those are mostly either early, inefficient transmitters or exceptionally high-powered ones.

Would it be possible to make a portable backpack-sized or even hand-held one for short-range communication, or is there something about the spark-generation process that requires a larger minimum size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About as small as you want.  Consider the [pioneering microwave work by J.C. Bose](https://www.smecc.org/j_c__bose_-_radio_and_microwaves.htm): the spark generator and antenna is only some cm across, the full pieces being mostly support.

Air ionization can act impressively quickly; spark gap risetime is mostly limited by spark length, hence we get risetimes of single to fractional ns in EMC work for example (EFT, ESD).  With a controlled spark length and environment, and transmission line techniques, bandwidths of many GHz are possible.  At some point, emission and ionization dynamics take over, and sparking (relaxation oscillator) gives way to a softer negative-resistance characteristic, and eventually stops altogether, at a cutoff frequency.  I don't know the cutoff frequency typical of sparks in air, but evidently it's in the 10s of GHz!

(For comparison, a similar experiment conducted with a small neon lamp, finds relaxation behavior up to maybe 10s of kHz, and negative resistance in the low 100s kHz, with little or no negative impedance beyond there.  The low pressure, modest dimensions, and characteristics of the gases used, cause fairly slow recombination.  The high pressure of atmospheric air causes much faster recombination.)

I don't know if he was able to achieve any kind of CW emission; I haven't read the original work.  If it was powered by electrostatic generator, it was probably impulsive regardless, though how long those impulses were (i.e. tone burst vs. impulse and ringdown) is still a valid question.  Not that it would've been resolvable at the time, but we can easily* scope such signals these days.

*Given suitable budget that is, heh.  But they are standard off-the-shelf equipment.  Or a wideband detector can be used, with a somewhat lower bandwidth scope to read the envelope.

CW, or tone burst, is an interesting possibility, as there were negative-resistance [arc type oscillator/amplifier systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_converter) in use, briefly before vacuum tubes took over.  It's conceivable that similar mechanisms could be employed at microwave frequencies, probably with some difficulty, and great precision (as you can't simply scale everything down proportionally, but parts that do, need to be proportionally more accurate).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the work of Jagadis Chandra Bose and the CW arc transmitters. I wasn't familiar with Bose's work at all, and only had a faint idea of how arc transmission worked. Both links led to treasure troves of information. Bose's work was decades ahead of everyone else - absolutely fascinating stuff!

Comment: It would be a fascinating amateur radio project to replicate one of those Bose experiments by detecting the signal from the ancient Bose-style spark-gap transmitter using a modern mmWave spectrum analyzer, or vice versa, detecting a CW signal from a modern mmWave generator or IC on a Bose-style crystal detector. The last time I checked, I found some university students from India actually did this several years ago and published a report, unfortunately the instructions were unclear for replication...

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason why you couldn't make one that would fit in the palm of your hand or smaller. The output power would likely be less than something where size, weight and power consumption (and dissipation) were not constrained.

They're not very efficient, and there are much better ways of getting more power in a narrow bandwidth. They're also probably illegal unless designed to be very unusually well filtered because they interfere with other transmitters/receivers since the noise they produce is wideband. They have more in common with a jammer than a modern transmitter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a car's ignition system - a potent spark generator.
This old mechanical spark generator consisted of a *distributor* and a *coil/transformer*. Both these need not be large. However, you'd need some method of rotating the distributor (in a car, it was mechanically connected to the rotating engine). This mechanical spark distributor could be hand-held.

Instead of a mechanically-operating distributor, an electronic switch can drive the coil to generate the spark. No rotation needed - you can drive the switch with an oscillator to generate the spark. Today, electronic switches have replaced the distributor.

But wait,
 if you can raise the oscillator's frequency up to a radio frequency, you don't really need a spark - the coil can now be efficiently coupled to a radiating antenna...and as Spehro Pefhany has mentioned, this method can be filtered far easier than a messy wide-bandwidth spark system, and efficiency converting DC from a battery into radio-frequency power is very good.

So the leap from spark transmitters to modern RF oscillator transmitters is not a huge leap. In the early days, fast switches that could switch millions of times each second were simply unavailable.